# dmath puts too many line breaks in

Tags: math-mode, equations, positioning, breqn

I've got the following code for an equation:

```
\begin{dmath}
    x \in A - B \leftrightarrow x \in A \textrm{ and } x \not\in B
\end{dmath}
```

It produces the output:

[image]

The equation really doesn't need so many line breaks, the whole thing could fit on one line. I then put a frame around it to see the bounds of the equation:

[image]

Is there a way to define the bounds of a `dmath` equation so that it isn't crammed into a really small box and given loads of line breaks?

Comment: instead of using `dmath`, if you know it can fit on one line, you can use the `equation` environment.  using the same environment for every display in your document may not be the best choice.

Comment: I'm targeting my documents at the Kindle, so over half of my equations need breaking up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that `breqn` makes more problems that it solves. By default, *every* relation symbol in `dmath` marks a line break point for alignment. Those you don't want should be hidden. Choose one of the methods below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
    x \in A - B \leftrightarrow x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B
\end{dmath}
\begin{dmath}
    x \hiderel{\in} A - B \leftrightarrow x \hiderel \in A \text{ and } x \hiderel{\notin} B
\end{dmath}
\begin{dmath}
    {x \in A - B} \leftrightarrow {x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B}
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\not\in` produces a wrong symbol and `\notin` should be used; this doesn't depend on `breqn`.

[image]

Comment: `s/that it solves/than it solves/`?

Comment: @morbusg Yes, typo. ;-)