# Multi-line equations in latex

Tags: equations

Is there anyway to write multi-line equations in latex automatically, I mean without using line break or other manually breaking lines.
is it possible to tell latex to begin with the next line when the first line reached the edge of the right margin of your page?

Comment: [**Welcome**](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to TeX.SX! [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3785/22492) answer might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `breqn` package for that, BUT...

- You **have** to read the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn.pdf) before using it (otherwise you won't understand, why nothing works as expected).
- Many of the TeX.SX users (including myself) believe, that [`breqn` creates more problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151071/10995) than it solves.

The following example is taken from the `breqn` manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
Replace $j$ by $h-j$ and by $k-j$ in these sums to get [cf.~(26)]
\begin{dmath}[label={sna74}]
  \frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(k,h,0) +\frac{3(h-1)}{h}\right)
  +\frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(h,k,0) +\frac{3(k-1)}{k}\right)
  =\frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{h}{k} +\frac{k}{h} +\frac{1}{hk}\right)
  +\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2h} -\frac{1}{2k},
\end{dmath}
which is equivalent to the desired result.
\end{document}
```

> [image]